# Value Of Type Form1.Data cannot be converted to Form1.Data() when passing parameters

Tags: vb.net

At the start of the program I define a new Public Structure 'Data':

```
Public Structure Data
        Dim car, grid, points As String
        Dim driver, team, fastestlap, racetime As String
End Structure
```

I then have the user input data and it is added to array displayData(5) of data type 'Data'.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim displayData(5) As Data
        Dim accepted As Boolean = False
        Dim temp As String
        Dim tempNum As Integer
        Dim output As String = ""
        Dim arraysize As Integer = 0

        For x = 0 To 5

            displayData(x).driver = InputBox("Please enter the name of driver number " & x + 1)

            temp = InputBox("Please enter the car number of driver number " & x + 1)

            While accepted = False
                If IsNumeric(temp) Then
                    accepted = True
                    displayData(x).car = temp
                Else
                    accepted = False
                    temp = InputBox("Error: integer not entered. Please enter the car number of driver number " & x + 1)
                End If
            End While

            accepted = False

            displayData(x).team = InputBox("Please enter the team name of driver number " & x + 1)

            temp = InputBox("Please enter the grid number of driver number " & x + 1)
            tempNum = Convert.ToInt32(temp)

            While accepted = False
                If IsNumeric(tempNum) Then
                    accepted = True
                    displayData(x).grid = temp
                Else
                    accepted = False
                    temp = InputBox("Error: integer not entered. Please enter the grid number of driver number " & x + 1)
                    tempNum = Convert.ToInt32(temp)
                End If
            End While

            accepted = False

            displayData(x).fastestlap = InputBox("Please enter the fastest lap of driver number " & x + 1)
            displayData(x).racetime = InputBox("Please enter the race time of driver number " & x + 1)

            temp = InputBox("Please enter the points of driver number " & x + 1)

            While accepted = False
                If IsNumeric(temp) Then
                    accepted = True
                    displayData(x).points = temp
                Else
                    accepted = False
                    temp = InputBox("Error: integer not entered. Please enter the points of driver number " & x + 1)
                End If
            End While

            accepted = False

            output = output & displayData(x).driver & "," & displayData(x).car & "," & displayData(x).team & "," & displayData(x).grid & "," & displayData(x).fastestlap & "," & displayData(x).racetime & "," & displayData(x).points & vbCrLf


        Next

        Dim filename As String = "U:\Subjects\Computing\AH Computing\Project Files\Leaderboard.csv"
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filename, output, True)

        bubbleSort(arraysize, displayData(6))

    End Sub
```

Above is the main bulk of my code. I am getting an error from typing in displayData(6) into bubblesort, which is defined here:

```
Public Sub bubbleSort(ByVal arraysize As Integer, ByVal displayData() As Data)

        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim outerloop As Integer

        For outerloop = (arraysize - 2) To 0 Step -1
            For counter = 0 To outerloop
                If displayData(counter).racetime > displayData(counter + 1).racetime Then
                    swap(displayData(counter).racetime, displayData(counter + 1).racetime)
                    swap(displayData(counter).car, displayData(counter + 1).car)
                    swap(displayData(counter).driver, displayData(counter + 1).driver)
                    swap(displayData(counter).points, displayData(counter + 1).points)
                    swap(displayData(counter).team, displayData(counter + 1).team)
                    swap(displayData(counter).fastestlap, displayData(counter + 1).fastestlap)
                    swap(displayData(counter).grid, displayData(counter + 1).grid)
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub
```

And apparently I need more normal text in order to save this. The bubble sort uses a swap algorithm that I defined in another part of the program, but it is incredibly simple and is 100% not the cause of the error so it seems unproductive to include it.

Comment: You need to show more code.  That code is not the code that is producing your error.  As an aside, that should be a class rather than a Structure.

Comment: Please show the code as @ChrisDunaway mentioned, specifically `it is added to array` how you are doing this.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Here ya go

Comment: There is a bug in this code, it never updates the `arraysize` variable so its value is always 0.  You discovered this bug, but then tried to fix it the wrong way.  You need bubbleSort(6, displayData).  But don't stop making it better.